# Mounting Network Share Folder using Active Directory Credentials

Tags: active-directory, ltsp

How do I mount a network share ( can be on startup or fstab ) in the windows server.
My Ubuntu is connected and login using Active Directory account, I need to find a way to let it mount department folder in network share using the account I'm login with

How to do this, a lot of cifs or smbclient way need to specify or manually insert the username or password in the script, I need to let it do it automatically.

Btw My Ubuntu is loaded from ltsp server, and there is a lot of other user using it too.

Answer (score 1):

I use this for mount directories from Windows domain file server. You can use it.

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Add this at the end:

```
//10.0.0.0/path /home/path cifs username=ADusername,password=ADpass 0 0
```